# Round Robin Tournament - Maximizing Cyclic Triplets

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, optimization

> A round robin tournament is a tournament in which every team plays every other team exactly once. Say we have a round robin tournament with $2n+1$ teams. What is the maximum number of sets of three teams ${A, B, C}$ in which $A$ beats $B$, $B$ beats $C$, and $C$ beats $A$?

$\textbf{What I've Done So Far:}$

I have noticed that there are $2n+1 \choose 3$ triplets of teams total, and that there can be only two types of triplets. The first type of is the type of triplet that the problem wants us to maximize, and the second type of triplet is in which one team beats both the other two. The amounts of each of these types of triplets must sum to $2n+1 \choose 3$.

$\textbf{Where I Need Help:}$

I don't know how to string the information I've gathered into an answer. From experience, I feel that we should probably relate the information gathered with some sort of inequality (i.e. AM-GM), but have no clue how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Set up the directed graph, and count the in and out degrees. Each cycle-triplet requires 3 in-out edges at a vertex, Each other-triplet requires 1 in-in, 1 in-out, 1 out-out edge. So ...

Comment: Thanks! My friend said that there's a really nice way to solve this using Cauchy's and I was wondering if anyone could solve it in that way as well?

Answer (score 1):

Set up the directed graph on $2n+1$ vertices where $ A \rightarrow B$ means that $A$ beats $B$.
We count the in-degree $I_i$ and out-degree $O_i$ of each vertex $i$, with $I_i + O_i = 2n$.

A 3-cycle $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow A$ requires 3 vertices to have an in-out pair of edges.
Any other tuple requires 1 vertex with in-in, 1 vertex with in-out, 1 vertex with out-out pair of edges.

Vertex $i$ contributes

- $I_i (I_i - 1)$ in-in counts
- $I_i O_i$ in-out counts
- $O_i (O_i - 1)$  out-out counts

Prove the following:

Claim 1: $ \sum I_i = \sum O_i $.

Claim 2: $ \sum I_i^2 = \sum O_i^2$.
Hint: use that fact that $I_i + O_i = 2n$ a constant.

Claim 3: $\sum I_i (I_i - 1) =  \sum O_i (O_i - 1)$
Note: This is implicit from the setup, but I wanted to establish it explicitly/independently.

Claim 4: Hence, the number of 3 cycles is $\frac{ \sum 2I_i O_o - I_i (I_i - 1 ) - O_i (O_i - 1) } { 6 } $.

Claim 5: This is maximized when $I_i = n, O_i = n$.

Claim 6: This can be achieved when team $i$ beats the next $n$ teams, and loses to the previous $n$ teams (indices evaluated mod $2n+1$ as always).